# How does Python assign and retrieve a DLL's global variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

### DLL written in C

```
extern int32_T myinput;
extern int32_T myoutput;

extern void initialize(void);
extern void run(void);
extern void terminate(void);

void run(void)
{
    myoutput = myinput * 2;
}
```

### Python script

```
from ctypes import*
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\myDLL.dll")
mydll.myinput = 10    # Question1
mydll.initialize()
mydll.run()
print(mydll.myoutput) # Question2
mydll.terminate()
```

### My expectation

```
20
```

### The actual output

```
<_FuncPtr object at 0x00000000023646C8>
```

### My Question

1. How to assign global variable in the DLL?
2. How to retrieve global variable in the DLL?

In short, could you modify my script to make the output be 20?

Comment: `CDLL` instances hook  `__getattr__` and `__getitem__` to return function pointers. Also, setting `mydll.myinput = 10` does nothing but set the `myinput` attribute of `mydll` to 10 in its `__dict__`; that has no affect whatsoever on the associated DLL. You want the `in_dll` constructor, e.g. `myinput = c_uint32.in_dll(mydll, 'myinput');` `myinput.value = 10`. All ctypes data types have this constructor.

Comment: @eryksun You solved my issue and taught me more. Thank you so much!

Comment: @kichik It is mostly duplicate. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Not a complete duplicate.  Neither the referenced question nor the ctypes documentation directly specify how to modify a value retrieved by in_dll, though the answer can eventually be inferred with sufficient reading.  Thank you @eryksun for supplying a direct answer to the question of how to modify such a value!